# Constructor reference incorrecty marked as error in IntelliJ 2017.1.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, java-8, method-reference

**EDIT:** As of IntelliJ version 2017.2 this issue has been fixed.

---

Java version: 1.8.0_131

IntelliJ IDEA version: 2017.1.4

I have this class:

```
public class MethodReferenceWithArguments {

    static <T, U> T createWith(Function<? super U, ? extends T> methodRef, U arg) {
        return methodRef.apply(arg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> map = createWith(
                TreeMap::new,
                Comparator.<String>reverseOrder());

        map.put("aaa", "ONE");
        map.put("zzz", "TWO");

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

With javac, it compiles fine and works fine. With IntelliJ, it compiles fine and works fine, however the `TreeMap::new` constructor reference is underlined with red and `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.TreeMap<K, V> to T` message is displayed on hover tooltip.

Does anybody know how to disable this misleading and annoying error message without turning off important, relevant error messages? Is this a bug? If yes, where can I report it?

Comment: You should report this to them, here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Suggested Title "Good code red: constructor reference can not be inferred".

Comment: that's *definitely* something to report to IDEA since it compiles just fine (without warnings) with JDK 8-131, 9-157 and latest eclipse - these are the ones I've tried.

Comment: @Ryan Reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175280)

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for checking other versions of java and eclipse. Here's the [submitted bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175280)

Comment: it was fixed in intellij idea 2017.2+

Comment: @holi-java Glad to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by **Intellij** can't infer the `TreeMap<K,V>` generic type, You can explicitly set the `K`, `V` type for resolving this warning, like:

```
    Map<String, String> map = createWith(
            TreeMap<String, String>::new,
            Comparator.<String>reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that method references allowed explicit generic type parameters.